# 'finalfit' loses labels when processing a continuous dependent variable

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

Normally, the function `finalfit` in the [finalfit](https://finalfit.org/index.html) package shows a regression table with variable's labels.
https://finalfit.org/articles/all_tables_examples.html#cross-tables

However, when a continuous variable including large amount of missing values is used as dependent variable, the function does not show labels but variables' names.

example

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
colon_s %>% 
  finalfit("nodes", "age") # "age" has label "Age (years)"
```

output

```
Dependent is not a factor and will be treated as a continuous variable
  Dependent: nodes         Mean (sd)       Coefficient (univariable)
1              age [18,85] 3.7 (3.6) -0.03 (-0.05 to -0.01, p=0.005)
      Coefficient (multivariable)
1 -0.03 (-0.05 to -0.01, p=0.005)
```

Can I fix it or is it inappropriate to use continuous variables?

device information

```
version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.2                         
year           2019                        
month          12                          
day            12                          
svn rev        77560                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
nickname       Dark and Stormy Night
```

```
packageVersion("finalfit")
[1] ‘0.9.7’
```

```
packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.8.3’
```

RStudio Version 1.2.5033

Comment: Sorry, this may happen when continuous variables predicts continuous variables. Missing value would be irrelevant. `colon_s %>% finalfit("nodes", "age")` would produce the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks.

This should work if you use finalfit 1.0.0, currently only available on github.

```
remotes::install_github('ewenharrison/finalfit')
library(finalfit)

colon_s %>% 
  finalfit("nodes", "age")

 Dependent: nodes              unit     value       Coefficient (univariable)     Coefficient (multivariable)
      Age (years) [18,85] Mean (sd) 3.7 (3.6) -0.03 (-0.05 to -0.01, p=0.005) -0.03 (-0.05 to -0.01, p=0.005)
```

Thanks again.